# How to multiply three matrices in tensorflow/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Suppose I have two matrices each one with a shape of `[20 256]` and when I want to multiply them I use the following

```
tf.matmul(v1, v2, transpose_b=True)
```

Now what if I have three matrices each with shape of `[20 256]`
Can I multiply it as

```
tf.matmul(v1, v2, v3, transpose_b=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do an element-wise multiplication

```
tf.math.multiply(v3, tf.math.multiply(v1, v2))
```

Please check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/multiply)

Comment: I don't know about `tf.math.multiply` and they have given very little documentation but can we use it for for matrices multiplication? because with `tf.matmul` we can directly multiply two matrices but I am not sure about three.

Comment: then use v1*v2*v3 for element-wise multiplication